# How to Get Output from a Print Statement of a Black Box Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

Let's say you have a function that you aren't allowed to modify, but you are able to call it. When you call it, how do you retrieve the output from the print statements such that you can store it in a variable?

Comment: `print(...)` always returns *None*. The only way I see to store the output of *print* in a variable is, to create a program calling the blackbox function and start this program via `var = subprocess.check_output(...)` from another program. This will store all your data from stdout in a variable `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The python print function is just a write operation to `sys.stdout` so you can implement a custom stdout class that switches `sys.stdout` with itself and implements a `write` method that will save the `write()` argument to a variable before calling the original method.

edit: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/119404-print-hook/ - this seems to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

out = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(out):
    print("bla")

out.getvalue() # returns 'bla\n'
```